# Delphi 7, indy9 tcp audio streaming

Tags: delphi, tcp, audio-recording, microphone, indy-9

I am trying to make an application that use audio streaming through TCP connection, Using Delphi 7 and Indy9.

More clearly, How i can stream input from Client microphone and send it to (TCP or HTTP Server)? Consider real time.

Thank you

Comment: How are you recording the stream? What format?

Comment: Im using StockAudioRecorder, Wave Audio

Comment: TCP is not the best choice for real-time streaming. Most streaming protocols are based on UDP instead. The early versions of Skype were written in Delphi and used Indy UDP components, for instance.

Comment: Look at [VC components of Lake of Soft](http://www.lakeofsoft.com/vc/)

Answer (score 2):

I never did this, but I think you can start with the basics ...

- Set the frame rate to be used, 8000hz is a good choice
- Choice a chunk size to capture from Microphone (1024, 2048, 4096,
  etc)
- Capture the audio from Microphone in short int or float32 (RAW Audio)
- Put this chunk in one socket buffer preferably UDP, and send to
  another side over UDP connection
- If you make a loop with this process are you sending audio data by
  socket
- Now The other side just need get the data from every UDP connection
  and play

This steps are a basic audio streaming :-)

In the future you might want to work with queuing, but that's another story